# linux programming: value of file descriptor is always 3

Tags: linux, unix, file-descriptor

I'm new to linux programming. I wrote a very simple program:

```c
#include stdio.h
#include fcntl.h
#include sys/ioctl.h
#include mtd/mtd-user.h
#include errno.h

int main( void )
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("test.target", O_RDWR);
    printf("var fd = %d\n", fd);
    close(fd);
    perror("perror output:");

    return 0;
}
```

test.target is created just using touch command. the program's output is:

```
var fd = 3
perror output:: Success
```

I've tried to open other files, and the file descriptor was always 3.I remembered it's value should be a larger number.If this program has some errors?

Comment: You said you solved it, but what was the solution?  You should accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: sorry. I'm new here, and I accepted the answer just now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems normal.  Processes start with pre-opened file descriptors: 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr.  Any new files you open should start with 3.  If you close a file, that file descriptor number will be re-used for any new files you open.

Answer (score 4):

If You would open another files without closing the previous one it'll be 4, 5, and so on.

For more info go to http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial
It's for bash, but the whole idea is universal.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        int     fd1;
        int     fd2;
        char    buffer1[] = "a.txt";
        char    buffer2[] = "b.txt";
    
        fd1 = open(buffer1, O_WRONLY);
        fd2 = open(buffer2, O_WRONLY);
        printf("%d\n", fd1);
        printf("%d\n", fd2);
    }
```

You can create two different files(a.txt and b.txt) and when you use open() it will get different File descriptor, for me I got 3,4

```
3
4
```

Because 0,1,2 have default value and meaning

- 0 : STDIN(standard input)
- 1 : STDOUT (standard output)
- 2 : STDERR
  (standard error)